# Unpacking .lz format: what does this command do?

Tags: command-line, compression, extract, initrd

I'm trying to unpack Ubuntu Desktop's initial ramdisk (`initrd.lz`) to inspect some casper components.

The **lz** format is indeed interesting, but what more surprises me is the unpacking method (that worked for me) as documented by RedHat [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/24029).

So when packing / unpacking, what does this set of commands actually do?
It forms one file named initrd, and then packs this file into initrd.lz.
It is very different then other command line methods I know of:

> xz/LZMA format - Extract / Uncompress:
>
> Uncompress and extract the contents of the image in the /boot/ directory:
>
> xz -dc < /boot/initrd-$(uname -r).img | cpio -idmv

**Command I used:**

```
xz -dc < initrd.lz | cpio -idmv
```

> xz/LZMA format - Repack / Recompress:
>
> find . 2>/dev/null | cpio -c -o | xz -9 --format=lzma > /boot/new.img

**Command I used:**

```
find . 2>/dev/null | cpio -c -o | xz -9 --format=lzma > initrd.lz
```

I understand that `2>/dev/null` means sending any error stream to `null` so they won't appear in the terminal, but what about the other chain of commands?

Answer (score 0):

Packing and unpacking are here two-step processes: when packing, the
entire directory is stored in an uncompressed single file,
presumably with an index which indicates which segment comes from
which file. Next, this single file is compressed.

Rather than creating an intermediate file, cpio sends this uncompressed single file to stdout, and the compressor receives it over stdin.

Analogously, unpacking sends the decompressed file via its stdout
to cpio's stdin, causing cpio to unpack its stdin.

The pipe symbol | indicates that the prior program's stdout is the
next program's stdin.

Read the man pages of xz and cpio for details, e.g. which options
cause the programs to use stdin and stdout rather than a file.